# Need to map image name same as Excel with extension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have some product name in excel need to map with an image in another folder with same product name with extension (.jpg,.png, ...) [mage from a particular folder is mapping with product name from A column in Excel sheet, the output is below.

[image]

Comment: shifting between jpg and png for each 2nd row?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to add the extension to the name of the images, right?

Comment: i have 1000 product name(A column ) in excel need to map the images with same product name with extension(jpg,png) format in download folder , need to map in excel sheet in B column

Comment: Since Appscript is executed in the cloud and not in your computer, I don't think it can read your local folder. However, this would be much easier if you do it with [Python](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) and then [update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate) or create the Sheet. You also have examples for Javascript if you feel more comfortable with that language.